# Override 'Login Forbidden' error message in meteor-useraccounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, telescope

I have built a basic Telescope Application. When I enter a wrong password it displays the error message **'Login Forbidden'**. I want to change the error message something relevant to the action. Where and what code should I include to make the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of replacing the `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` function, I recommend to configure a mapping via the [`meteor-accounts-t9n`](https://github.com/softwarerero/meteor-accounts-t9n) API (assuming you just want to replace the error message):

1. Run `meteor add softwarerero:accounts-t9n`
2. Add the following code:

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    T9n.map('en', {
        error: {
            accounts: {
                'Login forbidden': 'Credentials are incorrect!'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution it really worked. @Matthias

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using Meteor's Accounts package, since you haven't indicated otherwise.
You can override the `Accounts.validateLoginAttempt` function ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt)), to throw a `Meteor.Error`. As written in the docs:

> A validate login callback must return a truthy value for the login to proceed. > If the callback returns a falsy value or throws an exception, the login is > aborted. Throwing a `Meteor.Error` will report the error reason to the user.