# Laravel & Meteor password hashing

Tags: laravel, meteor, hash, bcrypt

I have two applications, one in Laravel 5.2 and one in Meteor. I want to collect hashes for passwords which are compatible with both platforms.

The database stores the hashes separately

- `password` for Laravel.
- `meteor_password` for Meteor.

Both platforms use bcrypt with 10 rounds by default, but Meteor appears to sha256 the plain password before bcrypt.

If Meteor creates password hash `abc`, I can sha256 the plain password, and compare it with `abc` using Laravel's internals, i.e. `Auth::attempt()`

```
$sha256 = hash('sha256', $request->get('password'), false);
```

This works. Laravel successfully authenticates the user.

However, if I register a new user in Laravel, and store the hash `meteor_password`, when authenticating against that hash in Meteor, it fails with the error message "Login Forbidden". [This error appears to be mean incorrect credentials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941460/override-login-forbidden-error-message-in-meteor-useraccounts)

I'm creating the hash in the same way as I did when I verified it in Laravel.

```
$meteor_password = bcrypt(hash('sha256', $plain, false));
```

It seems strange that it'd work one way and not the other so I assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2011, a bug was discovered in PHP's BCrypt implementation, so they [changed](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/108789/88377) the original `2a` version indicator to `2x` and `2y`, which is used today, to indicate that the password was hashed by the fixed version.

Therefore, the hash generated by PHP's `2y` should be identical to the one generated by node's `2a`.

The prefix should be changed in order to be correctly processed by the NPM module (used by Meteor), as it [does not acknowledge `2y`](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/175).

```php
$meteor_password = bcrypt(hash('sha256', $plain, false));
// replace it useing something like:
$meteor_password = str_replace('$2y', '$2a', $meteor_password);
// or
$meteor_password[2] = 'a';
```

Comment: Spot on, works as expected. Thanks for the links; interesting reads.

Comment: Great. BTW, the "cost" factor is exponential, so a cost of 10 is, in fact, (2^10=)1024 rounds, not 10 :)