# Meteor,why same password after hashing, different string stored in database

Tags: meteor, hash, passwords, sha256

I found that Meteor default use sha-256 to hash password. but I am confused that same password for each account after hashing become different string stored in the database. Anyone would tell the detail implementation, thx

Comment: It's because of the salt, which should be unique for each password. Hopefully this is not a single SHA256, because this would not be safe for storing passwords, recommended are BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt.

Comment: Meteor-Accounts package uses bcrypt I think

Comment: @martinstoeckli I want to know the exact value of the salt,salt with what, it may be a dynamic value or a database table field. Then I can implement it by myself in another system for integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Meteor docs, [accounts-password uses bcrypt](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_passwords).

If you look at the source code of [loginWithPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword), you should be able to find out where the salt is stored.  As a second source, read MasterAM's [answer to Laravel & Meteor password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232006/1967612) which indicates that Meteor from 2011 on uses [$2y$ hash strings, i.e. PHP CRYPT_BLOWFISH](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), which uses

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string. The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithmeter and must be in range 04-31, values outside this range will cause crypt() to fail. Versions of PHP before 5.3.7 only support "$2a$" as the salt prefix: PHP 5.3.7 introduced the new prefixes to fix a security weakness in the Blowfish implementation. Please refer to » this document for full details of the security fix, but to summarise, developers targeting only PHP 5.3.7 and later should use "$2y$" in preference to "$2a$".

Thus, look for the $2y$ string in the database, and extract the salt from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer let me know how bcrypt works.