# Migrating user information from Meteor to non-Meteor projects

Tags: meteor

I am migrating user documents in Mongo in my Meteor project to be used in a non-Meteor project (express backend).

I would like to know how to migrate the user data so that the users can continue to login using the same password in my non-Meteor app when I switch the backend away from Meteor.

Currently, the users in Mongo have this shape:

```
{
    "_id" : "some id",
    "createdAt" : date,
    "services" : {
        "password" : {
            "bcrypt" : "some hash"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [
                {
                    "when" : date,
                    "hashedToken" : "some hash"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "username" : "some username"
}
```

My plan is to use bcrypt to hash the plain password when user tries to login in a non-Meteor app, and compare it with the value for `services.password.bcrypt`. Would it work? What approach should I take?

Comment: Meteor uses bcrypt over a SHA-256, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35232006/268093) for a reference PHP implementation. Just make sure that bcrypt uses the same cost factor.

Comment: @MasterAM could you explain what cost factor I should choose? I am using the cost factor of 5 using bcrypt from npm, and it works now. But I don't know what it means to use the 'same' cost factor.

Comment: Also, you can add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.